# How to obtain widget/font size with different DPI and Resolutions in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, dpi

I have written a program with wxPython. We run that program on many different computers with different display configurations.

**Examples:**

- 1920x1080, DPI 100%
- 3000x2000, DPI 175%
- 1980x1080, DPI 150% (small 13" Display Laptop)

I code on an Full HD, DPI 100% display - the GUI looks fine! Especially on the 3000x2000. TextCtrls, BitmapButtons, and Images in general change their size (they get much smaller) and the GUI gets messed up for different resolutions. Same for the DPI 150%.

I tried to prevent it by setting the DPI awareness of my process in my main class but this doesn't work consistently.

Here is the how I set my DPI awareness:

```
import ctypes

# Query DPI Awareness (Windows 10 and 8)
awareness = ctypes.c_int()
errorCode = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetProcessDpiAwareness(0, ctypes.byref(awareness))

# Set DPI Awareness  (Windows 10 and 8)
errorCode = ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)
```

**Question:**

1. What do I need to do to make my GUI look at least similar on all DPI and resolution settings?
2. Are there special considerations for using images?
3. Do I need to scale widget/font size in my code directly?
4. Are there any tips with setting the size and distance of widgets in sizers?

I will attach a code example where I try to do as much size and positioning stuff as possible to give you guys a base to maybe fix something.

```
import wx
import wx.adv


class Mywin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title,size= (600,-1))
        
        self.SetSize(800,500)

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)        
        sizer_1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(125,-1), label='Order ID'), 0, wx.ALL , 5)
        sizer_1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(125,-1), label='Status'), 0, wx.ALL , 5)
        sizer_1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(125,-1), label='Creator'), 0, wx.ALL , 5)
        sizer_1.Add((-1, 5))
        sizer_1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(125,-1), label='Comment'), 0, wx.ALL , 5)
        sizer_1.Add((-1, 40))
        sizer_1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(125,-1), label='Customer ID'), 0, wx.ALL , 5)
        sizer_1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(125,-1), label='Customer Name'), 0, wx.ALL , 5)        
        sizer_1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(125,-1), label='Contact Person'), 0, wx.ALL , 5)
        sizer_1.Add((-1, 21))
        sizer_1.Add(wx.StaticText(self, size=(125,-1), label='Inquiry Date'), 0, wx.ALL , 5)


        ctrl_height = 25
        stati = ["Test", "Example"]
        
        tc_order_id = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(100, ctrl_height),style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        cb_status = wx.ComboBox(self,size=(100, ctrl_height), choices=stati, style=wx.CB_READONLY)        
        cb_creator = wx.ComboBox(self,size=(100, ctrl_height), choices=stati, style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        tc_comment = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=-1, value='', size=(300,55), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)        
        tc_customer_id = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(80, ctrl_height),style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)                             
        tc_customer_name = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(300, ctrl_height),style=wx.TE_READONLY)        
        tc_contact_id = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(80, ctrl_height),style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        
        calender_style = wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN | wx.adv.DP_SHOWCENTURY | wx.adv.DP_ALLOWNONE
        tc_order_date = wx.adv.GenericDatePickerCtrl(self, size=(90,ctrl_height), style = calender_style)
        
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2.Add(tc_order_id, 0)
        sizer_2.Add(cb_status,0, wx.TOP , 3)
        sizer_2.Add(cb_creator, wx.TOP , 2)
        sizer_2.Add(tc_comment, 0, wx.TOP, 9)
        sizer_2.Add(tc_customer_id, 0, wx.TOP, 4)
        sizer_2.Add(tc_customer_name, 0, wx.TOP, 4)
        sizer_2.Add(tc_contact_id, 0, wx.TOP, 4)
        sizer_2.Add(tc_order_date, 0, wx.TOP, 20)
        
        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mainsizer.Add(sizer_1)
        mainsizer.Add(sizer_2)
        
        self.SetSizer(mainsizer)
        
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        self.Layout()


demo = wx.App()
Mywin(None,'Example Code')
demo.MainLoop()
```

Comment: WXPython for mobile devices... Uf... Why? With WX you can do it but... why with wxpython? Why don't you use Kivy? that is made for this... I think you have chosen the wrong graphic library for your multi-device project.

https://kivy.org/#home

Comment: Jan Bodnar from Zet Code has an interesting solution that I believe might work for you. [link] http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/